# Symfony custom Constrait Validate for entity

Tags: php, symfony, validation, doctrine-orm

I use symfony 2.8 and I have some entity and I need validate this entity by some condition
I create constrait `ContainsInvValidator` and call validate service in action and validate entity but when debugged I did not entered in `ContainsInvValidator` how to correct use custom validate ?

this is my `ContainsInvValidator`

```
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ContainsInvValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (!$entity->getInvoiceNumber()) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->atPath('foo')
            ->addViolation();
    }

    if (!$entity->getReference()) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->atPath('foo')
            ->addViolation();
    }

    if (!$entity->getInvoiceDate()) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->atPath('foo')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
}
```

and `ContainsInv`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
* @Annotation
*/
class ContainsInv extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The string "{{ string }}" no valid.';
}
```

add config:

```
services:
app.contains_test_check_validator:
    class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsInv
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator }
```

and my entity class for which I create custom validator

```
/**
 * InboundInvoice
 * @ContainsInv(groups={"test_check"})
  */
class InboundInvoice
{
```

and then in my action

```
    public function handleInvoiceStatusAction(Request $request, InboundInvoice $invoice)
{
    $resultHandling = $invoice->changedStatus();
    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($invoice, [], ['test_check']);
```

and in variables `errors` I have

```
‌Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList::__set_state(array(
   'violations' => 
  array (
  ),
```

))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is valid for a property of a class. However if you want to validate the whole class (and not a single property), you have to overwrite the `getTargets` method in your `ContainsInv` Constraint class.

```
public function getTargets()
{
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
}
```

See also [Class Constraint Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator).